# Problems with file upload in Laravel

Tags: php, file, laravel, upload

I have a simple form with a file upload input that doesn't dump the file input value.

This is the form code that i have:

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="app-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="app-form-label">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="app-form-label">Ședință foto boudoir!</h4>
                    </div>

                    {!! Form::open(['url'=>'','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true, 'id' => 'model-form']) !!}
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('first_name', 'Nume') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('first_name', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                                         </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('last_name', 'Prenume') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('last_name', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
                                         </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('age') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('age', 'Vârsta') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('age', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('age'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('age') }}</strong>
                                         </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('sex') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('sex', 'Vârsta') !!}
                                    {!! Form::select('sex', ['M' => 'Masculin', 'F' => 'Feminin'], null, ['class' =>
                                    'form-control',
                                    'placeholder' =>
                        '-- Selectează --']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('sex'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('sex') }}</strong>
                                         </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!}
                                    {!! Form::email('email', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                         </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('phone', 'Telefon') !!}
                                    {!! Form::text('phone', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('phone'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
                                         </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('details') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    {!! Form::label('details', 'Detalii') !!}
                                    {!! Form::textarea('details', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 10]) !!}
                                    @if ($errors->has('details'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('details') }}</strong>
                                         </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {!! Form::label('image', 'Fotografii Reprezentative') !!}
                        {!! Form::file('image') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning card-2">Trimite Datele</button>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /End Modal -->
```

I use ajax to do the post with this code:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        $('#model-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'store',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log($('#image').val());
                }
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Now don't ask me why i set the csrf-token headers in ajax, that's another problem but for now, the problem is that is i do a $_POST & $_FILES dump after i submit the form, i have all the values of the form except the image file upload data.
I'm pulling my hair out with this so please help me!

Comment: dumping $_POST for the file?? You mean $_FILES? You should dump the $_FILES superglobal for your uploaded files

Comment: Yes, sorry, i did $_FILES to.

Comment: No, no console errors.

Comment: As long as i get all the input data except the image one...what do you think?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. All I did was copy and paste your html/js into a view, and dumped Request::all() inside a closure for Route::post('store'). Can you post what you have in routes.php for `Route::post('store', ...` and any related controller functions if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `enctype=multipart/form-data` whenever you're trying to send file data in the form like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

You can dump the inputs using laravel's [`dd()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-dd) method inside controller like this:

```
dd(request()->all());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!
I used dd(request)->all() and i saw the files...
Why did'nt work with var_dump($_FILES) ?!

Comment: Don't know truly but, Cheers, for solving your problem :D