# File upload laravel - file method of request returns null

Tags: laravel

I am making simple file upload page. 
My html code -

```
<form action="{{ $work_id }}/upload/" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="upload_file">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Faýly saýlaň</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" name="upload_file_submit" id="upload_file_submit" value="Ýüklemek">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My code in controller -

```
function uploadWorkFile(Request $request, $login, $work_id){
    $teacher_id_result = DB::select('select `id` from teacher where login = ?', [$login]);
    $teacher_id = $teacher_id_result[0]->id;
    $path = $request->file('upload_file')->storeAs('teacher_works/'.$teacher_id.'/'.$work_id.'/', $request->input('upload_file'));
    return $path;
}
```

My code in web.php

```
Route::get('/teacher/{login}/work_list/{work_id}/upload', 'TeacherController@uploadWorkFile');
```

I don't understand what happens there, please help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with file upload in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551671/problems-with-file-upload-in-laravel)

Comment: Did you add ```encrypted``` attribute inside your form tag, example in```<form action="/your_route" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">```

Comment: Yes I tried, same error - Call to a member function storeAs() on null

Comment: dd($request->all()) add this to your function to debug...maybe it's not getting the file

Comment: what I get - `array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "hLUJbuE4Mi8Wnk8ouIXfGxbGRDkXgt4dPZy6IBx9"
  "upload_file" => "screen.png"
  "upload_file_submit" => "Ýüklemek"
]`

Comment: you need to specify file path (where to store) as first argument in storeAs() and did you used storage link?

Comment: problem isn't in path, laravel doesn't reach storeAs(), because the file('upload_file') returns null

Comment: $request->input('upload_file')->storeAs